# How to map the values in dataframe in pandas using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have a df with values

```
df



name     marks     

mark      10
mark      40
tom       25
tom       20
mark      50
tom        5
tom       50
tom       25
tom       10
tom       15
```

How to sum the marks of names and count how many times it took

expected_output:

```
name     total     count


mark     100         3

tom      150         7
```

Comment: Can you explian more? How is possible distingush what values are in `50-1`, `50-2`, `50-3`?  Why are `50-3` for `tom=3` ?

Comment: Whats happens if changed `mark      40` to `mark      42` ? then is not possible get `50`, only `10 and then 52`

Comment: reframed the question. Pl check

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible use aggregate by named aggregations:

```
df = df.groupby('name').agg(total=('marks','sum'),
                            count=('marks','size')).reset_index()
print (df)
   name  total  count
0  mark    100      3
1   tom    150      7
```

Or with specify column after `groupby` and pass tuples:

```
df = df.groupby('name')['marks'].agg([('total', 'sum'),
                                      ('count','size')]).reset_index()
print (df)
   name  total  count
0  mark    100      3
1   tom    150      7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution. I'm doing it step-by-step for simplicity:

```
df["commulative_sum"] = df.groupby("name").cumsum()
df["commulative_sum_50"] = df["commulative_sum"] // 50
df["commulative_count"] = df.assign(one = 1).groupby("name").cumsum()["one"]

res = pd.pivot_table(df, index="name", columns="commulative_sum_50", values="commulative_count", aggfunc=min).drop(0, axis=1)

# the following two lines can be done in a loop if there are a lot of columns. I simplified it here. 
res[3] = res[3]-res[2]
res[2] = res[2]-res[1]
res.columns = ["50-" + str(c) for c in res.columns]
```

The result is:

```
      50-1  50-2  50-3
name                  
mark   2.0   1.0   NaN
tom    3.0   1.0   3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I see you changed the "to 50" part, this might not be revelant anymore.

I agree with Jezrael's answer, but in case you only want to count to 50, maybe something like this:

```
l = []
for name, group in df.groupby('name')['marks']:
    l.append({'name': name, 
              'total': group.sum(), 
              'count': group.loc[:group.eq(50).idxmax()].count()})
pd.DataFrame(l)

   name  total  count
0  mark    100      3
1   tom    150      4
```